# Anaconda : source conda activate didn't work on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, bash, anaconda

I just have latest Anaconda 3.18.5 installed on Mac OS.

I get "not found" result when I enter the text in terminal:

```
$ source conda activate snowflakes

-bash: source: command not found
```

The demo env is there, I can see it in folder.

conda-env: 2.4.4-py35_0

BTW, This question is similar to another thread:

[Why is Anaconda source activate non-existent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488081)

I have tried to fix it following this thread, bur didn't work:

[Anaconda activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220145)

Comment: Have you tried this in a new terminal?

Comment: I don't know why you `source` here, but `source`, being a shell builtin, doesn't exist?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have pre-pended anaconda/bin to your path and your env is called snowflake, you want

```
source activate snowflake
```

Comment: Thanks Mattexx!  

As your answer, after only remove the "conda" , the command works well. 

Misleading by the official online test drive.

Comment: Hi, I've created env, but source doesn't work #
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate titatic-py-env but ocmmand doesn't work, "source" not found